Does using a let statement in my PageServerLoad expose users data to other users?
In my sveltekit application, I have this code that requests multiple database tables and then passes them to the client as sections:
export const load: PageServerLoad = async ({ depends, locals: { supabase, user } }) => {
    
    /*
    all promises are wrapped in an async function and immediately invoked
    this is done because the PostgrestBuilder class is a PromiseLike object
    which cannot have a .catch() method called on it directly
    we wrapped the PostgrestBuilder in a promise so that we can call .catch() on the promise
    this is needed for preloading data in SvelteKit  
    find more info here:
    https://github.com/supabase/supabase-js/issues/1028
     */

  depends("supabase");
    const  digital  = (async () => await supabase.from('Digital').select().eq("user_id", user!.id).limit(1).single())();
  
    const financial = (async () => await supabase.from('Financial').select().eq("user_id", user!.id).limit(1).single())();

    const  funeral = (async () => await supabase.from('Funeral').select().eq("user_id", user!.id).limit(1).single())();

    const health = (async () => await supabase.from('Health').select().eq("user_id", user!.id).limit(1).single())();

    const insurance = (async () => await supabase.from('Insurance').select().eq("user_id", user!.id).limit(1).single())();

    const legacy = (async () => await supabase.from('Legacy').select().eq("user_id", user!.id).limit(1).single())();

    const legal = (async () => await supabase.from('Legal').select().eq("user_id", user!.id).limit(1).single())();

    const pets = (async () => await supabase.from('Pets').select().eq("user_id", user!.id).limit(1).single())();

// error handling for each section load
    digital.catch(e => console.error(e))
    financial.catch(e => console.error(e))
    funeral.catch(e => console.error(e))
    //... the other catch statements for every section
    
  let sections = {
    "Digital Estate": digital,
    "Financial": financial,
    "Funeral Planning": funeral,
    "Health and Medical": health,
    "Insurance": insurance,
    "Legacy":legacy,
    "Legal": legal,
    "Pets": pets, 
    
  }
//...
    return {sections: sections, //...};
  }

does the let sections {//..}` expose my data?
In the sveltekit docs it shows that you can expose data if you define a variable above the PageServer Load Function:
import type { PageServerLoad, Actions } from './$types';
let user;

export const load: PageServerLoad = () => {
    return { user };
};

export const actions = {
    default: async ({ request }) => {
        const data = await request.formData();

        // NEVER DO THIS!
        user = {
            name: data.get('name'),
            embarrassingSecret: data.get('secret')
        };
    }
} satisfies Actions

However since I define sections in the PageServerLoad itself then it should be safe right?
If not is there a better way to do this?
Also sidenote does anybody know a good way to make sure that client data isn't being exposed by the server, should I just run multiple sessions and then check the browser loads on each client? Thanks.

The issue is scoping. If a variable is defined at the level of the module, there is only one instance which is used by every call to the load function, hence data can be shared between different requests.
If the variable is defined in the load function, it will be scoped to a single execution of the load function and thus is not shared between requests.
Not sure what you exactly you mean in the second question. The easiest way to not have data leak is by not having any stat* on the server that persists between requests. If you need some kind of session data, you could use something like a Map that uses a cookie to identify the user, that way you can make sure that you never server data the user is not meant to access.
(Cleanup of unused data then becomes an issue though. In general it is really good if you don't need session data on the server at all.)
